# Как указать файлу записываться в темповую директорию сервера?

Tags: java, spring, filewriter

Как настроить путь для записи файла в приложении на Spring?

у меня создается файл html. Для теста я хочу положить его в

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/

но при writer = new FileWriter(fileTempJboss); получаю ошибку "неизвестная директория"

```
public void writeHTMLtoTempJBOSS() {
                File folder = new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/");
                File fileTempJboss = new File(folder , "file.html");
                FileWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter(fileTempJboss); // error
                    writer.write(String);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: если это web приложение, значит запись происходит в сервлете или я не прав ?

Comment: ну у меня есть rest контроллер который вызывает метод сервера "создать новую страницу" и в этом методе уже происходит создание нового файла и его запись.

Comment: я это к тому, что в сервлете есть статический метод, который позволяет получить путь к файлам относительно каталога, куда установлено само приложение, что-то вроде, `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` это выдаст полный путь к каталогу куда установлено приложение, то есть там, где лежит WEB-INF каталог, это должно быть так, если  я ничего не напутал

Comment: да понял что вы имели виду спасибо